# GRUB 2 resolution: Possible resolutions not listed in vbeinfo or hwinfo --framebuffer

Tags: grub2, resolution

I tried to set the same resolution i use for the Desktop for GRUB2 (1920x1080x32).

1. Why is this resolution neither listet in the output of `hwinfo --framebuffer` nor in that of `vbeinfo` on GRUB 2 console (available through `c` from GRUB menu)?
2. Why does `vbeinfo` show different resolutions than `hwinfo --framebuffer` even though both methods are recommended to find the available resolutions for GRUB 2?
3. Why does `vbeinfo` say `Preferred resolution: 1920x1080` even if this resolution is not contained in the output of `vbeinfo`?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards